# Where can I buy the Ubuntu phone to start developing apps?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is the Ubuntu Phone available anywhere yet? I want start developing apps.

I am very impatient to start to develop on real ubuntu phone.

Answer (score 15):

The dev preview is coming out on the 21st February. Be patient young Padawan. See:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TouchInstallProcess

This will be a flashable install to overwrite Android on a Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4. If you don't have one of those, I suggest you grab one.

Canonical will also be offering to flash phones at the Mobile World Congress later in the month. If you're scared of flashing your own hardware, this might be a good opportunity for you. (See the link above).

---

If you just want to get going writing apps, you can play around with the SDK already. That's available from here:

- http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/

Note that this is a technical preview. It's liable that the API will change and that might mean you need to do more work down the line.

Comment: It is already released, please update the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Times have changed, @sandy! Ubuntu Phones are arriving soon!

- See [BQ's Aquaris](http://www.bqreaders.com/gb/products/aquaris-5-hd.html)
- And [Xiaomi's Mi3](http://www.mi.com/en/mi3)

And more phones reportedly coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an Ubuntu Phone you can buy yet.  You can [install Ubuntu Touch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) on a Nexus 4 or Galaxy Nexus, or a number of [other Android devices](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices).

But you don't need a phone to start developing apps.  Because Ubuntu's goal is provide a single target platform for app developers, regardless of form factor, you can [write Ubuntu SDK Apps](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/) that run on the desktop just as well as they would on a phone.